# Only Know Password for One MySQL Login, Need to Reset Other Login...How?

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords, phpmyadmin, reset

I have access to the lesser account. I want the password to the All Privileges account. I've tried a few options but can't seem to get the password to reset.

Suggestions?

I'm also on Twitter asking for help... @BrentDPayne

Thanks,

Brent D. Payne

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - if mySQL is properly set up, and you're on a restricted account, this is not possible. It would be a security hole if it were.

You probably need to speak to your hosting provider or the administrator of the database to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Before you do this, make your firewall block connections to MySQL from everyone except you.
To turn off password verification, restart MySQL with

```
--skip-grant-tables
```

and reset the password. Restart again without this option.